# Vaadin: When is value change event fired for fields which are autocompleted by browser?

Tags: java, vaadin

About few months back, I had following issue in the login page of my vaadin application:

When the user clicks login button, application sometimes thinks that password field is empty, if the browser auto-completes the password field (remember password option).

This should be due to the fact that there was no event fired when browser automatically populates the password field, so that the value could be sent to server.

I didn't have a chance to analyze the issue earlier, but when I tried to reproduce the issue today, I couldn't reproduce it again.

I can think of two things which might have fixed the issue:

1. I have upgraded vaadin version, where vaadin has fixed this.
2. I have updated browser

If I add a value change listener to password field, the value change event fires as soon as I clicked on the login button.

Does anyone know why the value change listener fires when I click on login button (The focus is on the login button, so it can't be the focus change event) ?

Would it be safe to assume the issue is fixed now (value change listener would always fire when I click on login button, if the password is auto-completed by the browser)?

Comment: We did see this with Vaadin6, but not with Vaadin 7

Comment: Did you use .setImmediate(true); on your password field? If you didn't the value change event won't be triggered until the login button is clicked.